PyCharm: Configuring SSH interpreter - automation
I'd like to create a development environment using a python or a bash script.
I want to connect PyCharm to python interpreter in a docker container by running the script. Is that possible? What files have to be changed in the .idea directory and how?
I tried comparing the files before and after the interpreter was added manually, but haven't succeed connecting it automatically by applying the same changes. Maybe some other configuration has to be changed as well?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to be able to: 1. create docker container with python interpreter 2. run a script which will automatically configure pycharm to use that interpreter by providing it the container IP
